# react native make shadow more intense

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Having this react native style:

```
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
borderBottomColor: 'white', //'#FBFAFA',
borderBottomWidth: 10,
overflow: 'hidden',
shadowColor: '#099FD7',
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: -10 
},
shadowRadius: 10,
shadowOpacity: 100,
```

How can i make the shadow more intense? It's barely seeable in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: if you develop for android you may need to use [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation) property you can set it like `elevation: 1`

Comment: And how about ios?

Comment: I didn't try your code it should work as you expected for ios except you may need to change your style properties values

Comment: It works, but i want the shadow to be more noticeable. I need the shadow to be really big

Comment: That's because you set the offset.height to negative value try something else like `height: 3` and change the shadowColor to `#000000`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help..

Comment: I believe that's might be happening because the `borderBottomWidth: 10` try this and see if it's working `flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#ddd',
borderBottomWidth: 0,
overflow: 'hidden',
shadowColor: '#000',
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height:3
},
shadowRadius: 2,
shadowOpacity: 0.3,`

Comment: when borderbottom is 0 the shadow disaperas alltogehter

Comment: Any update guys.. really need  this functionality in there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this issue.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient
Here's an example:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/107

But there might be an issue with android with this.